# Is a pointer considered an unsigned value in C++?

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

Signed overflow is undefined.  Unsigned overflow is defined as modulo arithmetic.

So my question is, is the following defined or undefined:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdint>

struct X { int x;/* ... anything ... */ };

X array[3] = { 2, 3, 4 /* or other init values that is compatible with X */};
X* element = array + 1;

std::uintptr_t plus1 = 1;
std::uintptr_t minus1 = 0-plus1;


int main()
{
    printf("%p\n%p\n", element + plus1, array + 2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%p\n%p\n", element + minus1, array);
    assert(element + plus1 == array + 2);
    assert(element + minus1 == array);
}
```

Though I state `plus1`/`minus1`, I really mean any +/- value.  If I understand it correctly, this should work.  Am I correct?

Comment: I find your question a bit weird because you are using `std::uintptr_t` to store the pointer. You could have also used `std::intptr_t`, which is signed. Did you mean to use `X*` instead?

Comment: Overflow for `uintptr_t` is defined. For `intptr_t` is not. For `*` is not.

Comment: A pointer is neither signed nor unsigned. Pointer arithmetic has its own rules. `element[minus1]` attempts to access an element that's waaaay off the upper end of the array, so the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Are ppl downvoting because the question is poorly started, or because they don't like the question?

Comment: @Rakete1111, no, I'm using `std::uintptr_t` to store an offset using modulo arithmetic. Yes, I could have used `std::intptr_t`, but that isn't the question. I'm curious if this is defined.

Comment: The calculation of `element + minus1` gives undefined behaviour, both in the `printf()` and the `assert()`, since the result is outside the range of `array` (not between the first element and one past the end, inclusive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is defined in the abstract machine.

In the abstract machine, `ptr+x` is only valid if `ptr` exists within an object such that its address is within `-x` of the edge.

This abstract machine does not care about the specific size of pointers or signed or unsigned integers.  In this abstract machine, signed and unsigned integers have values that are *real integers*, or unspecified values.

`minus1` with a 32 bit `uintptr_t` is equal to 0xffffffff, a large positive integer.

Does `element` point within an object that is large enough that 0xffffffff*sizeof(X) later it is still within the object?  No it does not.

So `element+minus1` is an undefined operation.  Anything can happen.

On your hardware, a naive interpritation of pointer arithmetic into machine code *may* result in it wrapping around.  But relying on this isn't safe.

For one thing, optimizers sometimes like proving things.  If they prove `element` is greater than `array`'s address, then *no unsigned addition to `element` can possibly make it equal to `array`*.  So the compiler could optimize `element+unsigned value == array` to `false`.

Such optimizations can occur if you change optimization settings, upgrade your compiler, or completely innocuous things like change where it is inlined, or other code that is inlined, or heuristics at link time optimization, or the phase of the moon changing.

Relying on it working is dangerous, even when it does, as you now become responsible for auditing not the source code, but the machine code it generates.

Comment: So your saying that a pointer is treated as an unsigned value in this case? Is this statement listed in the standard somewhere?

Comment: @Adrian No I am not.  I am stating that pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of integers, as in mathematics, not in terms of `int`s.  And pointers are not integers in C++.  But you can add integers to them, and if the integers you add are within a certain range, you get a pointer back.  If not, the result is undefined.  Math on signed integral types has different cases where the result is undefined.  Math on unsigned integral types is mathematics mod 2^n for some n.

Comment: So what you are saying is that pointer arithmetic is not defined in terms of modulo operations.  That's fair.  And it defined in the standard that way?  Or is it omitted and is assumed that way?

Comment: @Adrian What is there to modulo against?  Again, pointers are not integers.  The modulo of (ptr+integer) is meaningless.  So yes, no mention of a meaningless modulo operation on a kind of thing that doesn't support modulo is made.  Pointers are thing to which integers can be added to, but the result is not an integer, it is a pointer (presuming the integer is within a certain bound).

Comment: Basically, if you have an array int a[10] then &a[0] to &a[10] are valid pointers (&a[10] may not be derefernced). If you have p = &a[3], then p-3 to p+7 are valid pointers with values &a[0] to &a[10]. If the _mathematical_ value of a variable x is not in the range -3 to +7 then p + x is undefined. unsigned int x = -1 is a very large integer, most likely around 2^32, and not in the range from -3 to +7 so p + x is undefined behaviour. Did I say anywhere that pointers are integers? I didn't, and they are not.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic is only well defined as long as the pointers involved remain within a single array object or just past the end of the array. So technically, the expression `element + minus1` is undefined behavior -- because `minus1` is a very large value, it runs past the end of the array.

Now in practice, this is likely to work, but it is still technically undefined.

Comment: Note that compilers would be perfectly justified in optimizing `element + minus1 == array` to be `false`.  There is no unsigned integer addition (under the standard) that can make `element` equal to `array`, and that is easy to prove.  So relying on it "work"ing may result in surprises the next time you change optimziation settings, update your compiler, or the moon's phase changes.

Answer (score 2):

- `std::uintptr_t` is an unsigned integral.
- `std::intptr_t` is an signed integral.

And so overflow of `std::uintptr_t` is defined, whereas the one of `std::intptr_t` lead to UB.

In addition, pointer arithmetic is only valid within array (to one past the end of an array).

`minus1` is the greatest number that `std::uintptr_t` can hold.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

> - If the pointer P points to the ith element of an array, then the expressions P+n, n+P, and P-n are pointers of the same type that point to the i+nth, i+nth, and i-nth element of the same array, respectively. The result of pointer addition may also be a one-past-the-end pointer (that is, pointer P such that the expression P-1 points to the last element of the array). Any other situations (that is, attempts to generate a pointer that isn't pointing at an element of the same array or one past the end) invoke undefined behavior.

`element + minus1` is not the same as `element - 1`.
`element + minus1` is outside valid range of array, and so lead to UB.

Comment: I think the question is asking if asking if `ptr + static_cast<std::uintptr_t>(-1)` will properly provide the element before `ptr`, assuming `ptr` is a pointer to an element in an array.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am asking.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Added that part.